# Does "senior" in a job title like "senior software developer" denote educational attainment?

Tags: negotiation, human-resources

In my performance review, my manager told me that he compared my salary against prevailing market rates by searching salary data for "Software Developer" and "C++ Developer". He said salary results for "Senior Software Developer" run $15-20K higher than results for the first two titles, but he did not use "Senior" because that word means that the title holder has earned a college degree (which I have not).

Curiously, HR shows my title as "Senior Software Developer". With 20+ years of professional development experience, seven years at my current position and a successful track record of technical leadership within the company, I think I've earned the designation of "Senior", as well as the extra 15-20K that go with it.

Is there a prevailing convention that "Senior" denotes someone with a degree, and is never given to someone who does not have a degree?

Comment: I am very grateful for both of the responses here. Unless further discussion contradicts what's been said so far, I'd like to believe that maybe I misinterpreted my manager's explanation as a generalization regarding the meaning of "senior" that perhaps he did not intend. Accordingly, I'll seek clarification on the point from him directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a prevailing convention that "Senior" denotes someone with a
>   degree, and is never given to someone who does not have a degree?

Not in my experience, no.

Pretty much every company creates job descriptions.

Each description indicates the minimum requirements for someone holding that position, the number of years experience required, along with job duties and other attributes.

I haven't ever seen a job description where the prefix "Senior" meant only "holds a degree". In general, it's never that simple. Virtually every job description specifies a mix of degree requirements and experience requirements. In many cases experience can substitute for a degree.

It's possible that in your shop the designation "Senior" denotes a degree and nobody who is degree-less could ever become a "Senior". In my part of the world, that would be unusual.

In every company where I have ever worked, someone with 20+ years of experience, plus 7 years in the position would almost certainly be at least a "Senior", if not beyond.

If management would let you review the written job descriptions for "Software Developer", "C++ Developer" and "Senior Software Developer" you could probably figure it out very quickly. (In my shop you could ask for and receive any job description on file.)

Answer (score 4):

Such a convention, if it exists, would exist in your company and most likely not in other places. The definition of the term "senior" is arbitrary and varies from organization to organization - The only thing that we can be certain across the board is  that "senior" is more senior than "junior" and that junior is higher than "noob", the lowest of the low :)

In your specific case and regarding your specific company: the only reason why your boss is not classifying you as "senior" is because he doesn't want to shell out the money. HR is classifying you as "senior". The perception that I am getting is that the company is classifying you as "senior", except when it comes to paying you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how it is where you work, but at most companies there is a HR code for the position (which defines the minimum salary + maximum salary and benefits you get), and then there is the job title.

Job code is generally numbers or letters, for example C1, C2, A1, etc.  Job titles are up to the department, but each job title is linked to one of the job codes.

As you go up or down a job code, your title can remain the same.  The salary is determined by the job code.  The role title is determined from the description.

The job description determines the requirements for the position; here is where usually they put any academic requirements.

However, this has absolutely no correlation with the title; so just because you don't have a post-graduate degree, doesn't mean you cannot be promoted to a position that has "senior" in the title. I am actually surprised that this was mentioned by your manager.